# numpy ndarray inside array using index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `numpy.ndarray` - `a`

and `a[0]` gives me:

`array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])`

also `a[0:1]` gives:

`array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])`

How can I make `a[0]` to the format `array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])` ie; in the format of array inside an array, like we do `[list[0]]`

Comment: How about `a[[0]]`?

Comment: @Divakar That works.!

Comment: what exactly is wrong with `a[0:1]`?

Comment: @narn I wish to the result of `a[0]` to be shown in the format how it displays `a[0:1]`. @Divakar 's solution worked.

Comment: But Divakar's snippet doesn't perform `a[0]`. If you were willing to use an expression that isn't `a[0]`, you could have just used `a[0:1]`. (It'd be faster, too, producing a view instead of a copy.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to reshape the array, so that every element of the first axis (every row) is an array of shape (1,m), instead of just (m,) you could do the following:

```
a = a[:,np.newaxis,:]
```

This way the (n,m) array is transformed into shape (n,1,m) and getting the first row with `a[0]` returns:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```